# Взаимодействие php и java (не js)

Tags: java

Есть программа, большую часть своей жизни она сидит в трее и должна иногда мигать иконкой, при двойном клике открывать вебкит. Мигает она или нет зависит от значения на пхп странице (там одно слово), например если там написано "clear" то иконка не мигает, если иное слово то должна мигать.Не могу понять, как можно вытянуть значение со странички. Вебкит написан на javafx, работа трея на awt.

---

```
    private void createAndShowGUI() {
            if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
                System.out.println("Don't tray!");
                return;
            }
            final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
            final TrayIcon trayIcon =
                    new TrayIcon(createImage("image/bulb.gif", "tray icon"));
            trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
            final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

            MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("Выход");
            popup.add(exitItem);
            trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);
            exitItem.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    tray.remove(trayIcon);
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

            try {
                tray.add(trayIcon);
            }   catch ( AWTException e) {
                System.out.println("Icon not be added.");
                return;
            }
            trayIcon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Application.launch(webwindow.class);
    //                Platform.runLater();
                }
            });


----------


    public class webwindow extends Application {
        private Scene scene;
        @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
            stage.setTitle("???");
            scene = new Scene(new Browser(),350,350);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
            Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            launch(args);
        }
    }
    class Browser extends Region {

        final WebView browser = new WebView();
        final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

        public Browser() {
            getStyleClass().add("browser");
            webEngine.load("???");
            getChildren().add(browser);

        }
        private Node createSpacer() {
            Region spacer = new Region();
            HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
            return spacer;
        }

        @Override protected void layoutChildren() {
            double w = getWidth();
            double h = getHeight();
            layoutInArea(browser,0,0,w,h,0, HPos.RIGHT, VPos.BOTTOM);
        }
    }
```

Это Main.java и webwindow.java

---

Код кривой, наверно еще нужно как-то реализовать многопоточность для работы трея и веба (при клике на трей открывается сцена и перекрывает собой работу трея), это немножко не по теме. Помогите с пхп сладить, гугль не помог только js выдает место java.
Ну и если кто знает как лучше переписать, или переделать все это, буду признателен за советы. В java около месяца, строго не судите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используем BufferedReader:

```
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        URL url = new URL("http://www.stranichka.com");
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        String line;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }

        System.out.println(sb);
    } finally {

        if (br != null) {
            br.close();
        }
    }
```

Или JSoup, или HTMLCleaner или Apache HttpClient или еще чего-нибудь.